# Text tag in adding 2 spaces in the begining of each line

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I have a scrollbar within a text widget, so I created a text tag to insert 2 spaces at the end of each line so that one letter words don't end up behind scrollbar, I made `insert lineend` as index for "space_tag", but it is also adding 2 additional spaces in first lines of text widget instances, can someone tell me why this is happening

The results are same if I use only `self.t.insert('insert lineend', '  ')` instead of using a tag

```
    self.t.bind("<Return>", self.save_task)
    self.t.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.strike_line)

    self.t.tag_add('space_tag', 'insert lineend')
    self.t.insert('insert lineend', '  ',  'space_tag')
```

Comment: Nothing will be behind the scrollbar unless you put the scorllbar _inside_ the text widget, which you shouldn't be doing. Instead of trying to figure out how to add two spaces, you should be solving the problem by moving the scrollbar outside of the text widget.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your problem without rest of the code but
inserting in a Text widget can be done as:

1.

```
self.t.insert(END, "your text here")
# This adds the text at the end of your current text
```

2.

```
self.t.insert('1.0', "your text here\n")
```

This adds your text at the start of your current text, i.e. line number `1.0`. `\n` enters  new line so the existing text is moved to the next line. You can change the `1.0` and replace with the line number you want to insert the text at.

If you want to add spaces after lines then just insert `"\n\n"`. This will add two new lines.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nmYVirT8 this is the code, I put the scrollbar directly in the textbox, one or two letter words could end up behind the scrollbar so I added a tag which adds two spaces at end of every line, when I run it, I see that there are 2 spaces are added in the beginning of first line of text widget also.